# Qt - How to save and load a QVector<QString> into multiple labels?

Tags: c++, qt, save, load, qvector

So I have multiple labels full of text, and I would like to save all of these labels in one go into a `QVector<QString>`. The Below code is what I have tried and it works but nothing is ever loaded when I load the saved file, I have checked the saved file with notepad and there is stuff in there, so maybe the load option is not working correctly? I'm not sure but help is appreciated. I also ask if you can suggest a better way of doing this if this seems like a bad or horribly inefficient way, again thanks for the help in advance.

The code for saving:

```
void Tasks::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{
const int length = 10;
QVector<QString> AllTasks(length);
AllTasks<<ui->label->text()<<ui->label_2->text()<<ui->label_3->text()<<ui->label_4->text()<<
          ui->label_5->text()<<ui->label_6->text()<<ui->label_10->text()<<ui->label_11->text()<<
          ui->label_12->text()<<ui->label_13->text();
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,tr("Save All Tasks"),"", tr("Tasks(*.tsk);;All Files (*)"));
QFile file(fileName);
if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
    QDataStream stream(&file);
    stream<<AllTasks;
}
file.close();
}
```

and the code for loading:

```
void Tasks::on_pushButton_6_clicked()
{
const int length = 10;
QVector<QString> AllTasks(length);
AllTasks<<ui->label->text()<<ui->label_2->text()<<ui->label_3->text()<<ui->label_4->text()<<
          ui->label_5->text()<<ui->label_6->text()<<ui->label_10->text()<<ui->label_11->text()<<
          ui->label_12->text()<<ui->label_13->text();
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Save Tasks"),"", tr("Task(*.tsk);;All Files (*)"));
QFile file(fileName);
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    QDataStream stream(&file);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
    stream>>AllTasks;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do this for saving:

```
AllTasks<<ui->label->text()<<ui->label_2->text()<<ui->label_3->text()<<ui->label_4->text()<<
      ui->label_5->text()<<ui->label_6->text()<<ui->label_10->text()<<ui->label_11->text()<<
      ui->label_12->text()<<ui->label_13->text();
```

and you do the same for loading. Why? The "data flows" in the direction of the operator (`<<` - into the `AllTasks`). This code does not create a special elements referencing the text objects of your labels.

It does exactly what it does for saving the data to a file. It fills up the `AllTasks`. Then, you fill it up even more with the data read from the file.

**Solution:** Change `<<` to `>>` and move the whole statement to be executed **after** you're done with reading the file.

**Edit:** There's no `operator>>`. Either do:

```
ui->label->setText(AllTasks.at(0));
ui->label_2->setText(AllTasks.at(1));
...
ui->label_13->setText(AllTasks.at(12));
```

or:

```
QVector<QLabel*> labels << ui->label << ui->label_2 << ... << ui->label_13;

for(int i = 0; i < labels.size() && i < AllTasks.size(); ++i)
    labels[i]->setText(AllTasks[i]);
```

Comment: i get an error and it says: 
no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are QVector<QString> and QString)

Comment: Oh, you'll need to do manual indexing then. There's no such operator, indeed.

Comment: may you explain how to? im not the best when it comes to qt.

Comment: `ui->label->setText(AllTasks.at(0));` and such. I hope you'll figure out the rest... It might be better if you could have those labels organized in a container.

Comment: thank you, however when I load it now, the label just goes blank, any idea why?

Comment: @Kitty No, I have no idea. Check if the `AllTasks` contains what it should.

Comment: at line "stream>>AllTasks", could it be that it somehow is trying to cram it all into one place in the vector? however even if it did this it would produce something on the first line, yet it doesn't, so i'm stumped.